# How do I make a custom component visible only to certain users on Salesforce home page?

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component

I created a custom visualforce page and put it in an iframe. I want to add this component to the Salesforce Home page, but only want it to be visible to certain users. Is there a way to do this rather than have it visible to everyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the users are of the same profile then You can create differnet home page layout include the component and associate a specific layout to the profile

setup-- customize -- home --home page layout

Comment: Tried that, but it somehow still shows the iframe for other users

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I had to set the security for that custom component.